# How do I detect the collison of components?

Tags: java, swing, components, collision-detection, jlabel

How do I detect the collision of components, specifically JLabels (or ImageIcons?)? I have tried this:

```
add(test1);
test1.setLocation(x, y);
add(test2);
test1.setLocation(x1, y1);
validate();

if(intersects(test1, test2))
{
    ehealth-=50;
}

public boolean intersects(JLabel testa, JLabel testb)
{
    boolean b3 = false;
    if(testa.contains(testb.getX(), testb.getY()))
    {
        b3 = true;
    }
    return b3;
}
```

When I run this, it does nothing!

I used to use `Rectangle`, but it didn't go well with me. I was thinking about an image with a border (using paint.net) and moving an imageicon, but I don't know how to get the x of an ImageIcon or detect collision. I don't know how to detect collision of a label or increase the location either.

I have searched for collision detection with components/ImageIcons, but nothing has came up. I have also searched for getting the x of ImageIcons.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try using `computeIntersection()` method from SwingUtilities. According to the [Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingUtilities.html#computeIntersection%28int,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20java.awt.Rectangle%29) for this method:

> Convenience to calculate the intersection of two rectangles without
>   allocating a new rectangle. If the two rectangles don't intersect,
>   then the returned rectangle begins at (0,0) and has zero width and
>   height.

Here's something that you can do with the above:

```
public boolean intersects(JLabel testa, JLabel testb){
    Rectangle rectB = testb.getBounds();

    Rectangle result = SwingUtilities.computeIntersection(testa.getX(), testa.getY(), testa.getWidth(), testa.getHeight(), rectB);

    return (result.getWidth() > 0 && result.getHeight() > 0);
}
```

Another way, as @Jakub suggested was to use `intersects()` method of Area. Sample code for that would be something like this:

```
public boolean intersects(JLabel testa, JLabel testb){
    Area areaA = new Area(testa.getBounds());
    Area areaB = new Area(testb.getBounds());

    return areaA.intersects(areaB.getBounds2D());
}
```

Comment: That seems to be dealing with rectangles instead of components. I am not using rectangles.

Comment: But your components have rectangles ?

Comment: @Coupon22: Just to clarify your doubt, the `getBounds()` method of the Component class *"gets the bounds of the component in the form of a Rectangle object. The bounds specify this component's width, height, and location relative to its parent."*

Comment: Then my next question is, how do I move a component/change the location after loading?

Comment: @Coupon22: Then that would become another question you might ask at stackoverflow :) A comment is ideally not a place to ask a question and usually its better to keep a single topic for each question :)

Answer (score 3):

You can write it by yourself, just remember, that two areas intersects if their areas overlay, not just when one contains the x and y coordinates (for which you are testing).

If I were you, I would use [`Area`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/geom/Area.html). It already has `contains` and `intersects` methods you need.