# Java, If a draggable object touches other object

Tags: java, draggable, jlabel

I have a code for dragging a label width mouse.

```
lbl_banner.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter()
{
    @Override
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
        //catching the current values for x,y coordinates on screen
        x_pressed = e.getX();
        y_pressed = e.getY();
    }
});

lbl_banner.addMouseMotionListener(new MouseMotionAdapter(){
    @Override
    public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e){
        //and when the Jlabel is dragged
        setLocation(e.getXOnScreen() - x_pressed, e.getYOnScreen() - y_pressed);
    }
});
```

Now, how do I make a function: While I'm dragging this label around the Screen, If the Label by dragging touches other object (label, button,...) to do something.

```
if(//labelTouchesSomething){//do something}
```

Answer (score 2):

While this is not technically a dragging but the dynamic move of a component (dragging is the transfer of contents in between components), you can compute the intersection of the current moving component against other components (this may need some navigation inside your hierarchy). May be this can help you: [How do I detect the collison of components?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12325553/how-do-i-detect-the-collison-of-components). You can also use the methods `contains` of `Component` to determine if some coordinates are inside a component or not.